# Why moment.js returns Invalid date

Tags: momentjs

I am using such code moment("24:33", "HH:mm").utc().format('HH:mm') and it returns Invalid date but should return "19:33" since there is 5 hour discrepancy between UTC and my local time. Why?

Answer (score 1):

moment accepts only values from 00:00 to 23:59.